# upload files from slack to s3 aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, slack, slack-api

I have a system that interfaces with Slack to back up each message in a channel.

I'm able to get the message object through a web hook, but there is a problem when files are included.

Inside `event.files` there is a `file` property, and I'm able to upload it to s3. But, the resulting file does not contain data for the actual file, but a html text document.

How could I retrieve the actual file programatically?

Comment: I've got the same issue. The problem here is that the information in the json you get from slack doens't include the actual file. 

I tried setting it up with zapier and upload the file to s3, but the resulting file was a html page. 

I think you would have to set up your own slackbot for this to work. Not sure why slack makes this so hard. They could at least give a direct download link that expired after some time to prevent being a file host.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to the authentication issue. Slack provides an HTML file instead of an actual file if authentication token is missing. So please make sure you have a valid authentication token passed while getting the file from Slack.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).